# How to concatenate two file and get grep -Fvf

Tags: shell

I have two files a1.txt and a2.txt

I want to concatenate two files and get the output from `grep -Fvf` from `cat` and the resulting file (`a3.txt`)

```
grep -Fvf `cat a1.txt>a2.txt` a3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cat` and pipes:

```
cat a1.txt a2.txt | grep -Fvf a3.txt
```